# Child Care Volunteering: Should I mention I was orphan?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-description

I have an interview for children patient support volunteer position in a hospital. I feel being an orphan at a young age -  I was 5 when my mother died and I was 15 when my father died - made me have better sympathy with children. Should I mention the same in interview or try to avoid this topic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, mention it.

I think this is an interesting situation because when you interview with a potential employer, a requirement is to have experience within the job you're applying. Being able to relate with these children will give you an advantage.

Comment: @Kilisi I misread the question. I apologize.